# Heterogenous Dynamo Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that holds two kinds of items.  Each Hash key has a handful of both of those item types, and each of those has a unique range key.  I've designed two corresponding and properly Dynamo-annotated Pojos, however, I am a little confused about querying.  I understand that I give the Query a Pojo class on which to Query, but if I query for a hash key giving it, say, PojoA for the expected class, will Dynamo automatically only get those PojoA's or will it also attempt to cast PojoB's found from the Hash key query as PojoA's?

Comment: it's going to probably attempt to cast. how would the query know to distinguish between the 2? if splitting this into 2 separate tables is not an option I would suggest having a strategy based on the hash key name and/or secondary indexes and simply dropping stuff that does not match what you expect based on the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB client will attempt to cast PojoBs as PojoAs. Ideally, records within a table should be of the same type.

If you really must use the mapper in such a situation, you can consider using the [marshallIntoObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#marshallIntoObject%28java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map%29) method. To use this method, you would

1. Use the low-level client to load the item from DynamoDB
2. Examine the item attributes to determine which pojo class it is. An attribute must serve as a differentiator.
3. Use the marshallIntoObject method on the item attributes to create an instance of the desired pojo class.